# Reorganize pandas data frame to display data horizontal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that displays which segments a particular organization belongs to. I want to prep the data frame for a left join merge on Org ID with other organization data.

Current, this df displays info top to bottom with each segment (with org id) in a separate row. Below is a sample of the df and an example of where I want to go with it.

**Current df structure**

[image]

**Needed df structure**

[image]

The number of segments is capped at 10 and each has a unique name such as Aerospace and Construction.

I have been digging around for a starting point to get this done for a few hours and no luck.

Could anyone provide a starting point for this?

**EDIT: Using pd.crosstab**

df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 13 entries, 0 to 12
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Org ID      13 non-null object
Org Name    13 non-null object
Segment     13 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 392.0+ bytes
```

Code:

```
file = "sample-data.csv"
path = root + file
name_cols = ['Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Segment']
pull_cols = ['Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Segment']
df = pd.read_csv(path, header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-1", names=name_cols, 
                       usecols=pull_cols, index_col=False)
df = pd.crosstab([df['Org ID'], df['Org Name']], df['Segment']).reset_index()
df.head(10)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: From your edit it seems that the csv header is a row of the dataframe. Can you have a look?

Comment: If you check `df['Org ID'].eq('Org ID').any()`, does it return `True`? It seems you have some undesired values in the ID and Name columns. If you have headers, `headers=None` should not be used otherwise, you need to add `df = df.iloc[1:]`.

Comment: It does return true

Comment: Try either `df = df.iloc[1:]` or remove `header=None`, which reads the header as a row in your data frame.

Comment: I removed the header=None and i get same result

Comment: You might need to remove `names=name_cols` as well.

Comment: I switched to pd.read_csv(path, encoding="ISO-8859-1", usecols=['Org ID', 'Org Name', 'Segment'], index_col=False, header=None) but get ValueError: Usecols do not match names.

Comment: Never mind it works. Forgot to take out the header=None

Comment: The only issue now is that I still have that first column which i assume is an index column (per image above). I do have index_col set to False.

Comment: The first column is actually not a column but index, It looks like a column, because of the `columns.name`. Try `df = pd.crosstab([df.A, df.B], df.C).reset_index(); df.columns.name = None`, you will see this more clearly.

Comment: Got it. Thank for all your help.

Comment: I don't know anything about your needs, but it looks like Segment is a variable, so ideally you'd want to keep it as a column (to keep your [data tidy](http://www.stat.wvu.edu/~jharner/courses/stat623/docs/tidy-dataJSS.pdf) and easy to manipulate later). Is there a specific reason you need to change your df structure? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @dangom I have two dfs. The one with segments and another that has all other org data. I want to add the segment df data as columns to the other org data df using a left join.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.crosstab`:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
pd.crosstab([df['Org ID'], df['Org Name']], df['Segment']).reset_index()
```

---

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
    'B': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    'C': ['seg1', 'seg1', 'seg2', 'seg2', 'seg3']
})

df = df.drop_duplicates()
pd.crosstab([df.A, df.B], df.C).reset_index()
#C  A   B   seg1    seg2    seg3
#0  a   1      1       0    0
#1  a   2      1       0    0
#2  b   2      0       1    0
#3  b   3      0       1    0
#4  c   4      0       0    1
```

Comment: Thanks for  quick reply. When I try this something gets messed up. I will update the question with the results in a sec.

Comment: If you just need an indicator of existence, then add `df.drop_duplicates` might help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Org ID','Org Name'], columns='Segment', 
               aggfunc='size', fill_value=0) \
  .reset_index()
```